# Flutter BottomNavigationBarItem.icon to use BottomNavigationBar.iconSize

Tags: flutter

I want to use custom `Widget` (**not** `Icon`/`ImageIcon`) for the bottom navigation bar icons, but how do I make them follow `iconSize`?

```
BottomNavigationBar(
  iconSize: 24, // Currently ignored...
  items: _menu(theme),
  ...
)

List<BottomNavigationBarItem> _menu(ThemeData theme) => _items
  .map((i) => BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: CustomWidget(), // ...by CustomWidget
        ...
      ))
  .toList();
```

Documentation for `BottomNavigationBarItem.icon`:

> Typically the icon is an Icon or an ImageIcon widget. If another type of widget is provided then it should configure itself to match the current IconTheme size and color.

What does it mean?

Comment: you can not do this with BottomNavigationBarItem, you have to build your own BottomNavigationBar and provide your own container

Comment: iconSize is configured in such a way that it is applicable only to the Icon Widget passed to icon argument. But I am not sure why you want iconSize,you can simply declare some custom property holding size and use that in your customWidget. Can you provide us code of customWidget?

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is set the size as a `const`, and use this const in the widgets

Comment: But I want to make use of `iconSize`.